# Issue with unwanted connection string appearing in my published web config

Tags: webdeploy

I’ve been testing the new web deploy tool with VS 2012 but I have this issue:

I get this extra connection string added to my published web config that I don't currently have in my projects web config.

```
   <add name="name" connectionString="name_ConnectionString" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Where could this be coming from? It seems like is a relic from past conn strings I've used..

Hope this explains my issue :0)
Thanks for any assistance

Quantum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to be coming from one of the web.config files.

Have you checked if a transform to your web.config is applied or not.  Check web.release.config, web.debug.config file to check if the connection string is still there.