# Duplicate Connection String Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, connection-string, config, xdt-transform

I have a website deployed in a server. One day it threw an error saying the `connection string` name is already added. I checked the web.config file and it has only one entry in that name. I removed the entry from the config. Now the website worked well and fetched data from database.

Note: When I changed the name of the config file it show error.

I think, the issue is – the connectionstring part is cached in memory. Is it so? How can we overcome this unwanted behavior?

Config Files in Source Code

Release Config

```
<system.web>
 <compilation xdt:Transform="RemoveAttributes(debug)" />

</system.web>
```

Debug Config

```
<system.web>

</system.web>
```

REFERENCES:

1. [Issue with unwanted connection string appearing in my published web config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13581892/issue-with-unwanted-connection-string-appearing-in-my-published-web-config)
2. [.NET 2.0 App.Config connection strings includes unwanted SQLExpress default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7573453/net-2-0-app-config-connection-strings-includes-unwanted-sqlexpress-default)

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16547034/encrypted-config-file-does-not-apply-remove-tag-in-connectionstrings for a related question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is not the issue - when you change the `web.config` file, the IIS process gets reset, so there can't be any caching involved.

What is more probable is that there is either a parent or child directory with a `web.config` file that contains the *same* connection string name - this is causing the error.

You can solve that in several ways:

- Ensure there is only one `web.config` in the correct scope with the connection string name
- Use the `remove` element:

  ```
  <connectionStrings>
   <remove name="theConnectionString" />
   <add name="theConnectionString" ... />
  <connectionStrings>
  ```

Refer [Encrypted config file does not apply “remove” tag in connectionStrings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16547034/encrypted-config-file-does-not-apply-remove-tag-in-connectionstrings) for a related question

Comment: Thanks. The `Remove` worked. Can you explain why it was working till yesterday and not working today? I have not made any changes to the website

Comment: Can xdt:Transform="RemoveAttributes(debug)" be any issue?

Comment: @Lijo - Who knows why? I am not sitting in front of your computer. You may have copied a `web.config` to the wrong directory. And that transformation is not likely to be involved.

Comment: Though it resolved my original problem, it doesn't work when I encrypted config files using aspnet_regiis as posted in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16547034/encrypted-config-file-does-not-apply-remove-tag-in-connectionstrings . How can we resolve this?