# Encrypted config file does not apply “remove” tag in connectionStrings

Tags: asp.net

Based on [Duplicate Connection String Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14258406/duplicate-connection-string-error) question I have added a `remove` tag before adding connectionstring. That resolved the problem for the original question.

But, when I applied RSA encryption for the web.config file (using aspnet_regiis) the error came back.

> Parser Error Message: The entry 'theConnectionString' has already been added.

I think, when encrypted, it is not calling the ‘remove’ statement. Is it so? Any workaround for this issue?

**Original Connectionstring**

```
<connectionStrings>
 <remove name="theConnectionString" />
 <add name="theConnectionString" ... />
<connectionStrings>
```

**Encrypted Config**

[image]

Comment: What does the element look like encrypted? (don't post the whole cipher text)

Comment: @Oded I have updated the question with a screenshot of the encrypted section. Please let me know if any issues in downloading the image.

Comment: When you manually decrypt it back, what does it look like?

Comment: @Oded When manually decrypted, the `remove` tag is not present. Is there anything that we can do to overcome this?

Comment: You need to find the "higher up" `web.config` file where it was added previously - possibly remove it there.

Comment: @Oded By using Clear instead of Remove as the first statement in the connectionstrings section, I could resolve the problem. Clear is reatained even after I manually decrypted the config file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `Clear` instead of `Remove` as the first statement in the connectionstrings section,  I could resolve the problem.

Note: `Clear` is retained even after I manually decrypted the config file. But `Remove` is not retained after encryption-decryption. [Thanks to @Oded for giving a comment to check this]

Refer [Connection Strings and Configuration Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494.aspx)

> The machine.config file also contains a connectionStrings section, which contains connection strings used by Visual Studio. When retrieving connection strings by provider name from the app.config file in a Windows application, the connection strings in machine.config get loaded first, and then the entries from app.config. Adding **clear** immediately after the connectionStrings element removes all inherited references from the data structure in memory, so that only the connection strings defined in the local app.config file are considered.